# We need maintain session through the WPF control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, session

I am using WPF in my Asp.net application and this application maintain Session(login/logout). in application we are open one user control in WPF but this WPF not maintain the session.

- One user control open in WPF.
- this control download the client system and after i start working on this control and after one hour i close the WPF screen and go to parent application and try to open any page or doing something it's showing session timeout and our login page are came.
- We want if we are doing work on WPF screen and come to the parent application not gone session.
- if we are working on WPF means we are working on application not a matter it's download the client system.
- WPF control not link the session to parent application.
- We are able to maintain seprate session for WPF but we want common session For both WPF and Application.

Comment: It's very long back question. so some have answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take one blank page and use one timer control on that page.
2. At the time of calling WPF content page, simply start the timer.
3. So time keeps the session until we not stop the timer.
4. At the time of closing the WPF page stops the timer.

After returning the main application you see session has not gone.

Note: This is not a permanent solution. Only temporary solution, but it's working on production and customer happy.